# HERE Map/MapView without using MapFragment

Tags: android, here-api

Is there a way to get a `Map or MapView` without placing a `MapFragmet` inside a `Layout`?

```
<com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/here_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I already tried to place a MapView directly in my layout but there is no method to initialize or request a Map from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView in your layout without the use of a fragment.

Simply call new `com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map()` and call `com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView#setMap( map )` to attach the map to the map view.

Note you can only attach each map to a single map view. Also, make sure to call `Mapview#onPause()` and `MapView#onResume()` or the underlying textureview will not work correctly!

References:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapView.html#setMap-com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map-

Comment: link is dead =(

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapView.html#setMap-com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map-