# Here Maps MapView does not work in Fragment

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to implement **Here Maps** in **Fragment** but it does not work. I got lots of crashes

**Crash Logs:**

```
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HERE SDK Version: 3.7.0.118
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$l.uncaughtException(MapsEngine.java:378)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HERE SDK Version: 3.7.0.118
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$l.uncaughtException(MapsEngine.java:378)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$l.uncaughtException(MapsEngine.java:379)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
     Caused by: com.here.android.mpa.common.UnintializedMapEngineException: Cannot create HERE SDK object before MapEngine is initialized. See MapEngine.init()
        at com.nokia.maps.BaseNativeObject.u(BaseNativeObject.java:39)
        at com.nokia.maps.BaseNativeObject.<init>(BaseNativeObject.java:26)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapImpl.<init>(MapImpl.java:424)
        at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.<init>(Map.java:710)
        at ie.globetech.transitconnex.activity.bustrips.BusTripFragment.onEngineInitializationCompleted(BusTripFragment.java:179)
        at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:279)
        at ie.globetech.transitconnex.activity.bustrips.BusTripFragment.onCreate(BusTripFragment.java:136)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2331)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1386)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1188)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1071)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:115)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2380)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
        at ie.globetech.transitconnex.activity.bustrips.BusTripMainActivity.onStart(BusTripMainActivity.java:125)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6965)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2934)
            ... 9 more
```

**Fragment Layout:**

```
<com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

**Fragment class:**

```
    public class BusTripFragment extends Fragment{

           private Activity mActivity;
           private Map map = null;
           private MapView mapView;

             @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    ApplicationContext appContext = new ApplicationContext(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
                    MapEngine.getInstance().init(appContext, this);

              }

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mActivity = (Activity) activity;
            //mCallbacks = (MyNavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {}
    }


        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trip_fragment, container, false);
               mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
               return view;      
                }

    @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {

            // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
            //map = mapFragment.getMap();

            isMapEngineInitialized = true;

            if (map == null) {
                map = new Map();
            }

            mapView.setMap(map);

            // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
            map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0), Map.Animation.NONE);

            // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
            map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
        }

     }
```

I am using HERE SDK Version: 3.7.0.118

I want through below therads

1. [HERE Map/MapView without using MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506270/here-map-mapview-without-using-mapfragment)

Any one has any idea how to deal with Here Maps MapView in Fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution and it worked very well. Removed **MapView** completely

Just added `FrameLayout` in layout xml of **Fragment**

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/simpleFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Now, in **onCreateView(...)** created **MapFragment** dynamically and added in **FrameLayout** and init

```
    MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, mapFragment).commit();

    mapFragment.init(mActivity, new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                    if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {

                        // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                        map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    } else {
                        logger.error("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment: " + error.getStackTrace());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Glad that it works for you, that is basically what Michael suggested, you slightly changed the way how you attach MapFragment to the activity. But as David rightly said, you can avoid using MapFragment at all, and use only MapView and MapEngine.init() to init engine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace:
Caused by: com.here.android.mpa.common.UnintializedMapEngineException: Cannot create HERE SDK object before MapEngine is initialized. See MapEngine.init()

And from your source code:
public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {

```
        // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
        //map = mapFragment.getMap();

        isMapEngineInitialized = true;
```

...
}

You are not checking for the error return code within onEngineInitializationCompleted.

The call stack you are seeing implies an error returned from the engine setup. Please print the error and we can find the proper solution.

Comment: App is crashing at this line  `map = new Map();` every time with error i posted in question. How to deal with map view in fragment ?

Comment: Hi, in your case it is failing because MapEngine init returned an error code. Your code snippit above: onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) does not handle the error argument. That's why you get the runtime exception stack trace. What is the Error returned in onEngineInitializationCompleted.

Comment: I got solution.